# Adding images onclick with a knockout observable

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, typescript

I'm using a api to get images it needs to be so that it first loads 10 images and when I click the button it has to add 10 images so I did this:

The observable amount for the images

```
public imageAmount:KnockoutObservable<number> = ko.observable(10);
```

Here I slice the array based on the imageAmount. This works fine.

```
var images = response.data.slice(0, this.imageAmount()).map((data=IImageData) =>
        {
            return {
                big: 'http://d1ftcqzt8gr3o4.cloudfront.net/'+ data.big,
                thumb: 'http://d1ftcqzt8gr3o4.cloudfront.net/'+ data.thumb
            }
        });
```

Then here i update the observable imageamount + 10 on click of the button.

```
public moreImages():void
{
    this.viewModel.imageAmount(this.viewModel.imageAmount() + 10);

}
```

now it is counting up but its not adding the images how can i do this?

HTML

[HTML on pastebin could'nt get right format on here](http://pastebin.com/UFra5SGi)

Comment: Can you share you HTML as well

Comment: I have added an answer. Hope it helps

Comment: Are you subscribing to the change of imageAmount to download more images? Or where is the call to server happening when you change the imageAmount

Answer (score 0):

You can use attribute bindings:

```
data-bind="attr:{src: $data.keyName}"
```

#### Example

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/28694/)

```js
var ViewModel = function(first, last) {
  this.img_arr = ko.observableArray([{
    index: 1,
    src: "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/604644048/sign051.gif"
  }, {
    index: 2,
    src: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f9/Wiktionary_small.svg/350px-Wiktionary_small.svg.png"
  }, {
    index: 3,
    src: "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/l/u/5/P/D/A/arrow-50x50-md.png"
  }])
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel("Planet", "Earth"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.1.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class='liveExample' data-bind="foreach:img_arr">
  <p data-bind="text:$data.index"></p>
  <img data-bind="attr:{src: $data.src}" alt="">
</div>
```